# c - change pointer of a variable in an array

Tags: c

I want a variable in an array to point to a given object:

```
typedef struct Object {
    void *key;
    struct Object *top;
    struct Object *next;
} Object;

typedef struct Table{
    Object *linkedObjects;
    size_t size, originalSize;
    HashFcn hfun;
    PrintFcn pfun;
    ComparisonFcn fcomp;
} Table;

Boolean InsertObject(TableP table, ObjectP object)
{
   int i = (*table->hfun)(object->key, table->size);
   table->linkedObjects[i] = object;
}
```

From previous questions i understand that doing this `table->linkedObjects[i]` is derefrencing the object and that is why i get the error `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Object’ from type ‘ObjectP’`. How can i tell the varaible at that point to point to the given object? i tried doing something like:

```
*(table->linkedObjects[i]) = object;
```

But that is obviously not the way to do it. Also should i free the object i got as a parameter?

Comment: If you want something to point at an object, that something should be a pointer. Perhaps you want `ObjectP *linkedObjects;` as the member of `struct Table`?

Comment: ObjectP and TableP are undefined. BTW exact duplicate of yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ObjectP` is typedeffed to `struct Object *` (which you haven't mentioned in the question), try this:

```
table->linkedObjects[i] = *object;
```

Remember that this will *copy* the contents of `object`.

If you don't want this behavior, and you'd like to keep the pointers instead, you should declare the `linkedObjects` member of your `Table` struct as `Object **` or `ObjectP *`.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the memory allocation with something like malloc(i*sizeof(Object*); and your object is also a pointer to Object, then it should work.